# Create an object of objects with merge

Tags: templating, array, merge

I'm trying to create an object of objects, can anyone suggest why `object` would only contain the last iteration of "itemObject"?

```
{% set object = {} %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section("mainSectionsStructure") %}
    {% set itemObject = {
            "title": entry.title,
            "link": entry.url
        } %}

    {% set object = object|merge(itemObject) %}

{% endfor %}

{{ object|json_encode() }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overriding the "title" and "link" properties on every iteration. Wrap the `itemObject` object in `[]` to merge the whole object into your array.

```
{% set object = object|merge([itemObject]) %}
```